# How to edit the display settings for Micropolis OUTSIDE of the game?

Tags: linux, micropolis

I recently installed [Micropolis](http://sourceforge.net/projects/micropolis.mirror/) on my laptop running Ubuntu 14.04. Unfortunately, the default resolution and aspect ratio of the game puts the settings button off my screen. I have tried finding a config file, but I can't seem to locate it. I've also tried Googling the problem, but I can't find any solutions that let me fix the problem out of the game.

So, basically, I want to know if there is some kind of command line argument I can pass Micropolis so that it will run in a lower resolution, or a file I can edit to achieve the same effect. I have to assume that I'm not the only person with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Upon much more extensive research (I did a Google image search for the main menu), it turns out there is no "Settings" option on the main menu. I have also found out that the  game window is resizable once the game actually starts. Unfortunately, this leaves a lot to be desired, especially considering the first report that I could find of this bug was in 2010.

**So, for anyone who is having the same problem as I did, just start a game and it should work just fine once the game is running.**

As a side note, I guess I just found my first open source video game project.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, I had the same issue and question and it worked great to just get into a game.